# Section spacing ignores figures placed at the top

Tags: spacing, floats, sectioning

IIUC, normally, a section only adds vertical space before it if the section is not the first thing in a column/page. To my surprise it acts the same after a `\begin{figure}[t] ... \end{figure}`. Is there a way to make sections treat these figures as they would anything else? *I.e.* make column 2 below act more like column 3, without affecting column 1?

### columns 1-2:

[image: pdf output page 1]

### columns 3-4:

[image: pdf output page 2]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-5\baselineskip}% this does not get applied after figures
    {\baselineskip}%
    {\Huge}
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0sp}

\providecommand\image[1]{
    \begin{figure}[t]%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (8,0) -- (8,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{\textbf{#1}}%
    \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}

\image{Good. A normal paragraph is nice and close to the caption.}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\image{Bad. A title should have space no matter what comes before it.}
\section{This title has almost no space before it}

\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\section{This title has much more space before it}
\textbf{Good. This is how a title usually adds space when anything is preceding it.}

\newpage
\section{This title rightly has no space before it}
\textbf{Good. There is nothing above the title in this column.}

\end{document}
```